# scrapy-playwright returning nothing but an error

Tags: scrapy, playwright-python

I'm learning Scrapy-playwright and it's fighting me. I'm attempting to gather store locations from a site using the CrawlSpider with a rule including a process_request that triggers the request to run through playwright. In my callback def I can print a value found on the page, but not return or yield anything. I've attempted to cache the data into an item, and return/yield a dict, all of which produces the error.

> ERROR: Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'Deferred'

I'm stumped.

```
import re
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from banners.items import StoreItem
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageCoroutine
from scrapy.http.response import Response

def set_playwright_true(request, response):
    request.meta["playwright"] = True
    request.meta["playwright_include_page"] = True
    request.meta["playwright_page_coroutines"] = ('wait_for_selector', 'span.store-name-city')
    return request

class StoreSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "retailer"
    allowed_domains = ['retailer.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.retailer.com/store/0000-city-ak']
    custom_settings = {
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True ,
        #'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': .5 ,
        #'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 3 ,
        'DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS': {
            "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler" ,
            "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler" ,
        } ,
        'TWISTED_REACTOR': "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor" ,
    }
    
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('directory/ak/anchorage'))),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'store/[0-9]+'), deny=(r'store/[0-9]+.+/.+')), callback='parse_item', follow=False, process_request=set_playwright_true),
    )

    async def parse_item(self, response):
        items = []
        item = StoreItem()
        self.logger.info('***** Start processing ' + response.url + '. *****')
        Name = response.css('meta[itemprop=alternateName]').attrib['content'] + ' - ' + response.css('span.store-name-city::text').get()
        print(Name)
        
        item['Name'] = Name
        item['StoreID'] = response.css('meta[itemprop=storeID]').attrib['content']
        item['Address1'] = response.css('span.store-address-line-1::text').get()
        item['City'] = response.css('span.store-address-city::text').get()
        item['State'] = response.css('span.store-address-state::text').get()
        item['Zip'] = response.css('span.store-address-postal::text').get()
        item['Phone'] = response.css('div.store-phone::text').get()
        item['Latitude'] = response.css('meta[itemprop=latitude]').attrib['content']
        item['Longitude'] = response.css('meta[itemprop=longitude]').attrib['content']
        
        items.append(item)
        return(items)
```

Comment: The error is clear on what you need to to. items is a list but it should be a dictionary or request or None. You can edit your parse method so that you return a dictionary instead.

Comment: @msenior_ If I redefine item as a dictionary, and return that instead of the list I get the same error. I'm not sure what you're recommending otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Changing parse_item from an async def to a plain def resolved the issue.

```
async def parse_item(self, response):
```

changed to

```
def parse_item(self, response):
```

Comment: But in your case your are defining    request.meta["playwright_include_page"] = True.
This is supposed to be passed when you want the page instance at the parse_item. 
So you can interact with it and this needs to be async like: 
`page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
await page.screenshot(path="./screenshot1.png")
`